# ffmpeg same frame rate for all input files and output file

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using `ffmpeg` to generate slide show of mix of images and videos. I want to set **frame rate** to all input files and output files.

```
ffmpeg -r 60 -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -i video3.mp4 -i video4.mp4 \
-filter_complex "\
[0:v]scale=w=1152:h=648,setdar=16/9[v0]; \
[1:v]scale=w=1152:h=648,setdar=16/9[v1]; \
[2:v]scale=w=1152:h=648,setdar=16/9[v2]; \
[3:v]scale=w=1152:h=648,setdar=16/9[v3]; \
[v0][v1][v2][v3]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" output.mp4 -y
```

I have put `-r 60` just after `ffmpeg` and before all input files.

**Will it copy to all input files as well as output files or I need to specify framerate separately for each input and output files?**

Answer (score 0):

Use the fps filter for each input i.e.

```
[0:v]scale=w=1152:h=648,setdar=16/9[v0];
```

becomes

```
[0:v]scale=w=1152:h=648,setdar=16/9,fps=60[v0];
```

Comment: should I remove `-r 60`?

Comment: Yes, remove it.

Comment: so, I do not need to specify input and output frame rates, adding `fps` will handle all

Comment: Yes, as long as you do it for video inputs.